# multi-character character constant and overflow in implicit constant conversion

Tags: c

I write a code is about black jack. 
 I cannot compiler it,it occurs warning. 
multi-character character constant and overflow in implicit constant conversion
 Can any one tell me what's going on.
 I have thought it for long time plz help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int flower;  
int k;
int add [13]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10,10,10};
char flower_all [4]={'\3','\4','\5','\6'};   
char number_all [13]={'A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K'};
char player_f[13],player_n[13];
char com_f[13],com_n[13];            
int poker [52]={0};            
int i,j,y,num,ans;
int player_p=0,com_p=0;
void wash (){    
int k;
k=rand()%52;
while(poker[k]==1)
{
    k=rand()%52;
}
poker[k]=1;
}
void give_card_p (){
char player_f[13],player_n[13];
int i,k;
int ans;
printf("請問是否要補牌? 1:要 2:不要");
scanf("%d",&ans);
fflush(stdin);
while (ans==1){
    wash();
    player_f[i]=flower_all[k/13];
    player_n[i]=number_all[k%13];
    player_p+=add[k%13];
    continue;
    if (player_p>21)
    break;
 }  
}
int main (){
srand(time(0));
char player_f[13],player_n[13];
int k;
for(i=0;i<2;i++){
    wash ();
    player_f[i]=flower_all[k/13];
    player_n[i]=number_all[k%13];
    player_p+=add[k%13];
}
for (i=0;i<2;i++){
   wash ();
   com_f[i]=flower_all[k/13];
   com_n[i]=number_all[k%13];
   com_p+=add[k%13];
}
printf("%c%c",player_f[i],player_n[i]);
fflush(stdin);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please consider creating an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please include the full text of any error messages and indicate which line it is failing on.

Answer (score 4):

Single quotes `'` denote 'character constants'. In the following line

```
char number_all [13]={'A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K'};
```

the `'10'` is a 'multi-character constant'. This is 'implementation defined' - that is, different compilers are free to interpret it in different ways. In this case given the error message you have provided, it is likely the source of your error. I would suggest using an [enumerated type](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/C_Language/enumerated_types.html) to represent your cards.

Comment: A literal has an address. Character *constants* do not have an address.

Comment: You can have multiple characters into them, but their meaning is implementation defined.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you are getting these two error

h.c:9:59: warning: multi-character character constant

h.c:9: warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion

It happens because in the program,

> char number_all
>   [13]={'A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K'};

you have **'10'** which is a multi character constant, the compiler is unable to convert it into a single character.

From Wikipedia:

> Individual character constants are single-quoted, e.g. 'A', and have
>   type int (in C++, char). The difference is that "A" represents a
>   null-terminated array of two characters, 'A' and '\0', whereas 'A'
>   directly represents the character value (65 if ASCII is used). The
>   same backslash-escapes are supported as for strings, except that (of
>   course) " can validly be used as a character without being escaped,
>   whereas ' must now be escaped.
>
> > A character constant cannot be empty (i.e. '' is invalid syntax),
> >     although a string may be (it still has the null terminating
> >     character). Multi-character constants (e.g. 'xy') are valid, although
> >     rarely useful — they let one store several characters in an integer
> >     (e.g. 4 ASCII characters can fit in a 32-bit integer, 8 in a 64-bit
> >     one). Since the order in which the characters are packed into an int
> >     is not specified, portable use of multi-character constants is
> >     difficult.